# Elements of a ring invertible in a faithfully flat algebra

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $R\to S$ be a commutative algebra with $S\neq 0$ free as an $R$-module.
Is it true that for the units of these rings we have $U(R)=U(S)\cap R$ ?

Comment: let$f:k\to 0$ be zero map, with k a field.

Comment: @user 1: ok, question now modified.

Comment: It has been suggested that the question would be more appropriate at Math.SE. But here is a hint: supposing that $r \in R$ has an inverse $s$ in $S$, pick a basis $e_i$ and write left multiplication by $s$ as a matrix with respect to the basis. So $s e_i = \sum_j a_{ij} e_j$ with the $a_{ij} \in R$. And then...

Answer (score 5):

This is true under the weaker assumption that $S$ is faithfully flat over $R$.
Given $a\in U(S)\cap R$, the map $a.:R\to R$ becomes surjective after tensoring by $S$: hence  it was actually surjective and there exists $b\in R$ with $a.b=1$.
  Thus $a$ is a unit in $R$ and $U(S)\cap R\subset U(R)$. The other inclusion is trivial.